# Add fields in internal product page shopify

Tags: shopify-app

Im new with shopify and i want to add a new field in the internal product page, but i dont want to use an app to do it for me, i want to do an app that add this field, for example with odoo you can create a module that extend the model and view and show the new field.

Thanks a lot

John

Answer (score 0):

You can use metafields to add custom fields. It is what you are looking for adding custom options.

With metafields, you can store custom attribute on different objects